# Get total memory usage in blackberry

Tags: memory, blackberry

How can I get the Total memory usage by all running applications? Basically I want to find whether the memory usage is greater than 30% or above.

Comment: Check [Memory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Memory.html) class of RIM API SDK.

Comment: Why don't you use some of the profiling tools?

Comment: check this link:       http://software.crackberry.com/product.asp?id=344913

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Rafael, you can make use of the [Memory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Memory.html) class. More specifically, you can use the following which will help you:

```
   Memory.getRAMStats().getFree();
   Memory.getRAMStats().getAllocated());
```

If you compare the two mathematically, you can get the percentage from that.